# How can I solve whitespace error when sending mail in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, email, smtp, whitespace

I am trying to send an email from spring boot, but I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: jakarta.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string ``; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
jakarta.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string ``
    at jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1345)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1193)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parseHeader(InternetAddress.java:755)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:746)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getFrom(MimeMessage.java:374)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1773)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:465)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
    at email.exist.EmailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:77)
    at email.exist.EmailController.emailConfirm(EmailController.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:913)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I checked both the recipient's email address and the sender's email address, but there was no whitespace.

Currently, the files for my email transmission are as follows

0. properties - I have the following settings in the properties

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
 
# admin google account
AdminMail.id = 'account@gmail.com'
AdminMail.password = 'use AppPassword'
```

1. EmailConfig - A file that sets the sender email address, this part works fine
2. EmailController - This part also works fine
3. EmailService - Interface for EmailServiceImpl
4. EmailServiceImpl - I'm getting an error at this part

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;
 
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService{
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender emailSender;
 
    public static final String ePw = createKey();
 
    private MimeMessage createMessage(String to)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(to);
        System.out.println(ePw);
        MimeMessage  message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, to);
        message.setSubject("Email send test");
 
        String msgg="";
        msgg+= "<div style='margin:20px;'>";
        msgg+= "<h1>Hello1</h1>";
        msgg+= "<br>";
        msgg+= "<p>please paste this code<p>";
        msgg+= "<br>";
        msgg+= "<p>thank you<p>";
        msgg+= "<br>";
        msgg+= "<div align='center' style='border:1px solid black; font-family:verdana';>";
        msgg+= "<h3 style='color:blue;'>Sign Up code</h3>";
        msgg+= "<div style='font-size:130%'>";
        msgg+= "CODE : <strong>";
        msgg+= ePw+"</strong><div><br/> ";
        msgg+= "</div>";
  
        return message;
    }
 
    public static String createKey() {
        StringBuffer key = new StringBuffer();
        Random rnd = new Random();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(3);
 
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    key.append((char) ((int) (rnd.nextInt(26)) + 97));
                    //  a~z  (ex. 1+97=98 => (char)98 = 'b')
                    break;
                case 1:
                    key.append((char) ((int) (rnd.nextInt(26)) + 65));
                    //  A~Z
                    break;
                case 2:
                    key.append((rnd.nextInt(10)));
                    // 0~9
                    break;
            }
        }
        return key.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public String sendSimpleMessage(String to)throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MimeMessage message = createMessage(to);
        try{
            emailSender.send(message);
        }catch(MailException es){
            es.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return ePw;
    }
```

I confirmed that an error occurs when calling emailSender.send(message) in the sendSimpleMessage method.

Both the recipient's and sender's e-mail addresses were checked, and the smtp settings of the e-mail were also checked. App password for gmail was also applied.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I solved it by adding the code below to the createMessage method.

```
message.setText(msgg, "utf-8", "html");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender email in properties","
sender's name"));
```